# An example of holomorphic function

Tags: complex-analysis

Make an examples $f:\Bbb{C}\to\Bbb{C}$ holomorphic (If it exists) with the properties:(Justify your answer)

$f(x)=x^2$ for all $x\in\Bbb{R}$ and $f(iy)=y^4$ for all $y\in\Bbb{R}$.

My attempt for (1) was $f(z)=\left(\dfrac{z+\bar{z}}{2}\right)^2+\left(\dfrac{z-\bar{z}}{2i}\right)^4$
but I do not know how I can prove or disprove it.

Answer (score 1):

Your example doesn't work, since your functions is *not* holomorphic. By the identity theorem, if $(\forall x\in\mathbb{R}):f(x)=x^2$, then $(\forall z\in\mathbb{C}):f(z)=z^2$. So, there is no such function.

You should delete your two other questions and ask them as two individual questions, showing your effort. Otherwise, this question will likely be closed as “too broad”.